# How to upgrade product price when qty(quantity) change at product view page in magento 2.4.x?

Tags: magento2, product, admin, price, qty

I want to change product price at product view page when qty was upgrade by end user how can I do that,

https://prnt.sc/14tzj72

[image]

Comment: It's not an answer but you can look into bundle product module, specifically price-bundle.js file to see how bundle products update price on quantity change.